# Why is my custom modal window "outside / above" the window?

Tags: css

I have a homemade modal window that appears "above" or "outside" the actual window. To reach the button, you have to scroll down the page. The problem is the modal appears at the top of the page (not the window) It is hard to describe, so here's a testing link to view the behavior:

https://www.voyagersopris.com/testing/modal-testing#modal

Click the "OPEN MODAL" button.

The CSS that defines the position is:

```
    .form-modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
```

JavaScript sets the display to `block` when the SHOW MODAL button is clicked.

So, my question is **How do I make the modal appear within the window and not at the top of the page that is outside the window?** FYI Bootstrap's Modal window displayed the same behavior, with the additional issue of appearing behind the overlay.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `position:fixed` positions an element relative to current [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Viewport), which is the currently visible section of the window object.

However, using 3d-transforms on elements you are setting them as current viewport for all their children.

In your case,

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

... applied to `.slide-menu-wrapper` sets it as viewport for all its children. Which causes the modal to position itself relative to `.slide-menu-wrapper`.

Removing `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` from `.slide-menu-wrapper` fixes the problem (or overriding it with `-webkit-transform: none`).

You probably applied that style to prevent some flickering of some animation. You'll need to go into more detail and apply that rule to a more immediate parent of your problematic animated element.

On a separate note, `.slide-menu-wrapper` doesn't really sound like a class that should wrap your entire page, does it?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it. Amazing! I just tested it and it's true.

Comment: Thank you Andrei for the clear explanation. I'm unfamiliar with `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` That fixed it. And agreed regarding the naming used for this page wrapping div. There are some theme elements that a previous developer was using that have proven to be problematic.